# Rectangle triangle of sides natural

Tags: geometry, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Is there a rectangle triangle such that each side length is a natural number, and such that its area is a perfect square?

Comment: According to wikipedia, as $a=k(m^2-n^2)$, $b=2kmn$, the area is $k^2mn(m^2-n^2)$, so we want $n(m-n)m(m+n)$ to be full square..  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple

Comment: No, there does not exist such a triangle. Apparently, that's what Fermat proved to, consequently, prove that $x^4+y^4=z^4$ does not have integer solutions such that $xyz\neq 0$. He used the infinite descent method. It is discussed [here](http://fermatslasttheorem.blogspot.ca/2005/05/fermats-one-proof.html).

Comment: Integer areas of rational right-triangles are called "congruent numbers", q.v. The smallest is $5$, so you not only can't get a square, you can't get $2$ or $3$ times a square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider sides of triangle to be $(a,b,c)$

You have a relation : $a^2+b^2=c^2$

And you need to check whether $a \cdot b =2k^2$, where $k^2$ is the area of the triangle.

From solution of $Pythagorean$ triplets

We have $a=(2mn)d$ and $b=(m^2-m^2)d$

Area of triangle becomes $\triangle =(mn)(m^2-n^2)(d^2)$ here GCD ($m,n)=1$

Fermat: "Consequently there would exist two square numbers the sum and difference of which would both be squares."

Comment: True, but not actually an answer to the question, is it?

Comment: Not really, its just kind of a hint. Comments on the questions speak more than this answer, I suppose.